# The jar files in -classpath is not recognized when I try to run .jar program

Tags: jdbc, jar, driver, classpath, mysql-connector

I created a simple MySQL java program named, DBDemo.java. This class is in the package named `dbdemo`.

I put the mysql-connector-java.jar file under a directory named `lib`, so I run the program as:

`java -classpath ./lib/mysql-connector-java.jar;. dbdemo.DBDemo`

It works with no problem.

Now, I created my program into a JAR file, named DBDemo.jar.  So, I tried:

`java -classpath ./lib/mysql-connector-java.jar;. -jar DBDemo.jar`

But, an errors comes as:

> SQLException on database creation: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

It seems that the mysql-connector-java.jar in `-classpath` works with my DBDemo.class file program, however, the `-classpath` is not accessible if I try to run my DBDemo.jar file.

How can I make my `-classpath` accessible with my DBDemo.jar program?

I am using Java 15 on Windows 10.

Comment: When you use `-jar`, the class path is fully defined by the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest of the JAR. Any value set through `-classpath` is ignored. Either use `java -classpath ./lib/mysql-connector-java.jar;DBDemo.jar dbdemo.DBDemo`, or make sure your JAR contains the right `Class-Path` field in its manifest.

Comment: Thank you, Mark Rotteveel.  Your suggestion works.  However, is there a link to how to define Class-Path entry in the manifest of a JAR?

Comment: That depends on how you create the JAR. Build tools like Gradle and Maven have features built-in for this.